# Loss of Object detection model using ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_300x300_coco increases after every 10k-12k steps

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I'm re-training `ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_300x300_coco` object detection model on a custom dataset. The dataset consists of approx 2.6k images and 19 classes. After the training step reaches 10k-12k the loss graph starts increasing. This happens even if I change my model to `ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco` and at the same step range. I couldn't find anything that is related to this behaviour in the config file. Also this disappers when using `faster_rcnn` models. When the issue arises the mAP becomes almost constant. Also tha accuracy doesn't go beyond 50%. Can anyone explain this behaviour ?

Sample Dataset:

[image]

Loss Graph

a) ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_300x300_coco
[image: ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_300x300_coco]

b) ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco

[image]

Config File:
a) ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_300x300_coco

https://pastebin.com/BBwqEruK

b) ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco

https://pastebin.com/F8K0BhQV

Answer (score 3):

What about your training loss? Notice that `total_loss` is the validation loss here.

If your training loss is decreasing while the validation loss is increasing, this is clearly a sign of overfitting, you may use regularization loss during training by adding the following in the config file, in part `train_config`

```
add_regularization_loss: true
```

just as `batch_size: 24`